# StreamReader skips further lines

Tags: c#

Given a rawtext file named "config.cfg" with the following contents:

```
entry1=value
entry2=value
entry3=value
```

The following function only reads the first entry into the SortedList, "entry1".  I am unsure why this occurs - it should be reading all entries into the SortedList.

```
static public void setConfigValue(string key, object value)
{
    var config = File.OpenText("./config.cfg");
    SortedList<string, string> entries = new SortedList<string, string>();

    while (config.BaseStream.Position < config.BaseStream.Length)
    {
        string temp = config.ReadLine();

        if (temp != null)
        {
            string[] entry = temp.Split('=');
            entries.Add(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }
    }
    config.Close();

    if (!entries.ContainsKey(key)) entries.Add(key, value.ToString());
    else entries[key] = value.ToString();

    List<string> listToSave = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++) listToSave.Add(entries.Keys[i] + "=" + entries.Values[i]);

    File.WriteAllLines("./config.cfg", listToSave);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BaseStream.Position is not a normal way of checking for End-Of-File.

MSDN suggests using `config.Peek() >= 0` as your while condition. You could also check against `EndOfStream`. I'm guessing the position check isn't doing what you think it is.

Using `File.ReadLines`, or even `File.ReadAllText.Split('\n')` would work as well. (The second would potentially have a problem with carriage returns, but at least you get all the data).

MSDN for reading all lines: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    static public void setConfigValue(string key, object value)
    {
        var settings = File.ReadAllLines("config.cfg")
            .Select((p) =>
                {
                    string[] temp = p.Split('=');
                    return new { Key = temp[0], Value = temp[1] };
                })
            .ToDictionary((p) => p.Key, (p) => p.Value);

        settings[key] = value.ToString();

        var newContents = settings
            .Select((p) => string.Concat(p.Key, '=', p.Value))
            .OrderBy((p) => p, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines("config.cfg", newContents);
    }
```